# Unable to find database name using EntityCommandExecutionException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

In one of my WPF application, I am handling my exceptions at global level. I used below code to handle the exception.

```
 private void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception is System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException)
        {
            var entityException = e.Exception as System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException;
            if (entityException.HResult == -2146232004) // Schema is different than expected
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Database exists but schema is different");
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

It is working as expected. But I am using multiple DbContext having different connection strings and I want to display the name of database in the error. I cannot find Connection string in EntityCommandExecutionException. How to get database name?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that somewhere in your error handler you have access to the DbContext object upon which the error took place, then you can use the dbContextObject.Database.Connection property to get to the SqlConnection object which provides various properties about the database connection including the name of the database.

Comment: I am searching for that "somewhere". I cannot find dbContext in exception handler.

Comment: Ah.  Right - that was not clear in the question.  A simple approach might be to capture the exception where it is raised and then raise a custom exception where you can put a reference to the appropriate DbContext object into the Exception Data, and stash the original exception into an inner exception.